# How to resolve cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

**TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined**

contact-keeper/client/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:42

```
  39 |  * @public
  40 |  */
  41 | 
> 42 | var res = Object.create(http.ServerResponse.prototype)
  43 | 
  44 | /**
  45 |  * Module exports.
```

Comment: I don't see how that could happen unless some modules are corrupted or mismatched versions of modules.  I'd suggest removing the Express module and all of its dependencies and then reinstalling it.  If the `http` module is separately installed, you should also remove that and reinstall.  And, make sure you don't have any of your own code that is assigning to `http.ServerResponse`.

Comment: @Hamza Iftikhar were you able to find solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

try adding

```
target: 'node'
```

to your **webpack** config